# Kubernetes nifi application deployment with configuration management

Tags: kubernetes, configuration-management

I have deployed my Ni-Fi application using Kubernetes on-prem setup. Now the image which i am using to spin up the docker container is from docker private registry, which i can see when i deployed using Daemon sets service because my requirement is to spin up only one Pod per node and i don't want to replicate my pod if that is killed/terminated.
           having said that i want to listen this applications on some ports...so my questions are as below
1) How to open multiple ports for the application which are running on multiple nodes on single pod.
2) i have some configuration files which are in a shell script with environment variables defined within..how to inject this script on to my application which is already running.

Comment: I would suggest you also to adjust a title of your question as right now it suggests issue when using Kubernetes together with some Configuration Management tool (Chef, Puppet, Anisble) whereas it's in fact about general Kubernetes concepts like Services.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on StackExchange @Ravikumar

Ad. 1 - How to open multiple ports for the application which are running on multiple nodes on single pod

1. You need to define what ports are opened in your container inside of Pod spec. e.g:

> `apiVersion: v1
>   kind: Pod
>   metadata:
>     labels:
>       app: example-app
>     name: example-app
>     namespace: default
>   spec:
>     containers:
>       name: multi-port
>       image: perl
>       command:
>         - perl
>         - -Mbignum=bpi
>         - -wle
>         - print bpi(2000)
>       ports:
>         - containerPort: 8080
>         - containerPort: 8081`

2. Expose your workload externally using [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), e.g.

> `apiVersion: v1
>   kind: Service
>   metadata:
>     name: my-app-svc
>   spec:
>     selector:
>       app: example-app
>     ports:
>       - name: http
>         protocol: TCP
>         port: 8080
>         targetPort: 8080
>       - name: monitoring
>         protocol: TCP
>         port: 8081
>         targetPort: 8081`

From now on you can refer to your app, distributed over different nodes (Pod replicas) using service DNS name + Port: e.g. my-app-svc:8080 or my-app-svc:8081. Keep in mind this is a valid only within cluster, if your want to expose your app outside of Kubernetes cluster, check other option like ServiceType of LoadBalancer or NodePort, as described in official doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

Ad. 2 - For defining environment variables for Pod's container check in official doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

Comment: i have tried the following yaml file with DS it generated one pod per node with the image pulled and also listening on the ports which i mentioned inside, however i am unable to see the commands which are mounted as volume is not passed to the images...can someone tell me why? or what this file needs to execute those scripts within the container image

Comment: It would be really better if you create a new topic on Stack, your problem seems to be not related anyhow to the original question.

Comment: yes it is @ https://superuser.com/questions/1446034/kubernetes-daemonsets-with-volume-mount-and-shell-script